# Why electrons in an atom don't radiate photons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, orbitals

Consider the $s$ orbital of an helium atom. The electron can be anywhere around (or even in) the nucleus. Electrons, like all charges, create electric fields. When the atom interacts with other atoms the electron should have a definite location (like in Van-der-Waals interaction). This means electrons are now found in a definite spot, which leads to a creation of electric field. Changing electric field create photons, so during wavefunction collapse there should be radiation. Why is this not the case? Electrons pop in and out of existence in an orbital as the wavefunction collapses because of interaction with other particles. If this is not the case, then how can Van-der-Waals forces work without definite position of the electrons. So, electric fields pop in and out or in other words, a changing electric field at different areas are created that propagate as radiation.

Comment: Physics is not math. That line of reasoning simply doesn't work in the world. Why? Nobody knows. All we have is models that *do* work. The working models predict no radiation from the ground state.

Answer (score 3):

When you say "[t]he electron can be anywhere around (or even in) the nucleus," you assume that the electron has a well defined position, which is not how quantum mechanics treats it. In quantum mechanics, particles do not have well defined positions, so when we say that an electron is in a certain orbital, we are not directly referring to a probability distribution of where the electron might be, rather we are saying that its state can be described by a certain set of quantum numbers. This fact still holds when talking about multiple atoms interacting, although in that case, we generally cannot describe the states precisely, instead approximating them using techniques like perturbation theory.

The notion of charges creating electric fields according to Coulomb's Law describes how charged particles interact with the electric field in the theory of classical electrodynamics. However, photons do not exist in classical electrodynamics, so it makes no sense to talk about the production of photons based on that theory. Instead, you need to use quantum electrodynamics to properly talk about the interaction between electrons and photons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your classical intuition from electromagnetism, you should consider the average position of the electron. So, although there is a certain probability that the electron is in any position, on average, it is steady at a distance of $\frac{3}{2}a_0$ from the nucleus, with $a_0$ the Bohr radius.

Answer (score 1):

You have repeated a collection of theoretical ideas, and you have trouble fitting them together. This is because they are different theories that in fact don't fit together.

Review the bidding. It used to be, physicists thought that electric charge was a fluid, like water or heat. It was only natural to assume that charge flowed through a metal wire like water flows through pipes, or like heat flows through a metal wire.

Back in the days when physicists thought that charge was a fluid, they noticed that charges attracted and repelled each other, and the same giant collection of charges would attract and repel other collections of charges as if they all did it continuously. They assumed that each bit of charge affected all the other charges all the time, since they had no particular reason to assume otherwise.

**Accelerating** charges had an effect in all directions perpendicular to their acceleration, that declined linearly with distance (or maybe with time, same thing). Also the effect spread out to the sides some, reduced with the angle, the same formula as for polarization. (And the radiation force lines up with the acceleration, which gives us the polarization of the light.)

This all worked too, for some things where it was measured. They assumed there were no exceptions, because why should they assume otherwise?

Now fast-forward to around 1900. They found that some matter is quantized.  sometimes electric charge is quantized. Water is quantized, it's made of H2O molecules which continually break up and reform, and when there are a whole lot of them the fluid approximation works. They found no examples of matter that was not quantized, so they naturally assumed that all matter was in the form of discrete quantized atoms.

Charges can get rubbed off of atoms in unit amounts. When there are a whole lot of them then the fluid approximation works well.

So electric charge was observed to sometimes be quantized, and nobody had a definite example of fractional charge, so physicists assumed that charge is always quantized. Since they make that assumption, if they observe a fractional charge they aren't looking for, they might assume a different mass etc to account for the discrepancy.

If you assume that charges are little spheres, then mathematically their effects are the same as points at their center of charge. That's very convenient. So until there was reason to think that charges were not little spheres, physicists naturally assumed they were little spheres.

Sometimes, atoms emit quanta of light. It follows that atoms also sometimes absorb the same quantized amount of light. So maybe what's going on is that all light travels as discrete quantized packets, and the photon that one atom emits is the same photon that another atom absorbs? But in that case how does a single photon travel through two different slits? It was a great mystery which required a great deal of handwaving to reconcile. Once you accept that radiation is always quantized and not waves, that each electron moving in a plasma is absorbing and emitting strict quanta, explanations generally get more complicated.

When physicists tried to study individual subatomic particles, they found that the blunt measuring tools they had available changed the particles while measuring them. Make two kinds of measurements one after the other, and you clobber the first value when you measure the second. So you can't know everything you'd need to assume particles are in definite places with definite velocities. Whether or not they **really** are at definite places with definite velocities, you can't know it. So we wound up with math that works on what can be measured, instead of hypothetical models that can never be tested. It's very hard to understand exactly what the quantum mechanics is measuring or what it means, and the stories people make up about it mostly don't make sense. But it's argued that if it predicts the right answers then that's all that's important and it doesn't need to make sense.

> The electron can be anywhere around (or even in) the nucleus.

Theory of electrons, yes.

> Electrons, like all charges, create electric fields.

From Maxwell's equations. A reasonable hypothesis, that all charges always create electric fields. Maxwell didn't know about electrons, but if he had heard of them this is what he would have expected them to do.

> When the atom interacts with other atoms the electron should have a definite location (like in Van-der-Waals interaction).

Pre-Heisenberg theory. Maybe electrons do have definite locations, but if we find out an eletron's definite location then we know hardly anything else about it.

> This means electrons are now found in a definite spot, which leads to a creation of electric field.

Maxwell was fine with electric fields being produced by irregular blobs of charge, not exactly a definite spot. Quantum theory ditto.

> Changing electric field create photons,

Photon theory. Maxwell thought it creates radiation which if periodic will trace out waves.

> so during wavefunction collapse there should be radiation.

Not really quantum theory, or anything else either. You get a wavefunction that represents the limited amount you know mixed with what you don't know. When you learn more, the wavefunction collapses into something more definite, with the new things you know mixed with what you still don't know. Or anyway that's one way to look at it. There's no necessity for there to be radiation when you find out something new. I think. My interpretation of QM may not be standard.

You have a mishmash of assumptions from different times and places. They don't fit together, and there's no reason they should. The assumptions were made at different times and places by people who were trying to explain different things that didn't make sense.